# Arabic Text stroke overlap (with zero fill)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, stroke, fill, arabic

How do I remove the stroke overlap between the individual Arabic characters when I use zero fill or even white fill?

[image]

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, this is for Adobe illustrator CS6

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to outline your text. Set the stroke and fill using the Appearance panel (*Window → Appearance*) and drag the stroke to the bottom so that it is behind everything else.

If you're happy with a solid fill then you're done.

If you want a transparent fill then set the opacity of your fill to 0 (with a solid color fill, not a transparent fill) and check "Transparency Knockout Group" on the layers transparency options.

[image]

Note, this has nothing to do with Arabic text and the same problem exists for any script.

Answer (score 1):

Add a white fill to all shapes then go to **Pathfinder -> Unite** then *remove fill* if you feel like it.

> This assumes you are treating your text as artwork. If the text is
>   still editable, right click on it and select **Create Outlines** and only then do the above.

---

### *PS: While my method works well, you should use Cai's technique since it's a less destructive one and it will allow you further text modifications.*